# lateinit property not initialized after pick file explorer

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

I have an activity that let user select file from explorer, retrieve the result in `onActivityResult()` and save the result inside an object called `Property`

I have a lateinit variable as follow :

`lateinit var uploadProperties: Property`

And the code to open explorer (permission already granted) :

```
fun openExplorer(property: Property) {
    uploadProperties = property
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    intent.type = Constants.ALL_FILE
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.select_file)),
        REQ_FILE
    )
}
```

an then onActivityResult(), I convert the data to base64 and assign it to the Property

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQ_FILE -> {
                data?.let {
                    val base64 = data.toBase64()

                    uploadProperties.let {
                        value = base64
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that at some cases, I got these error report on crashlytics :

```
Caused by kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException
lateinit property uploadProperties has not been initialized
```

I tried this many times, and I got these error only a few times (doesn't know what trigger this). But some user complaints that the app always crashed after choosing files from explorer. I checked on crashlytics and the message are as mentioned above.

I have tried to debug using breakpoint before `startActivityForResult()`. The variable `uploadProperties` is already initialized and the value is correct. But after choosing file from explorer, in some cases, the app still crashed with `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`.

Any idea what caused this error and how to fix this?

Comment: Your process might have been terminated while your app's UI was in the background. Or, your activity might have been destroyed and recreated as part of returning control to you, due to a configuration change while the user had the Storage Access Framework UI in the foreground.

Comment: Go into developer options and enable "don't keep Activities" - your app will reproduce that crash every time.

Comment: Ah i see, thats might be possible. Any idea to work around these?

Comment: I have tried to put these variable as companion object to avoid lifecycle but it still happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the case where your apps process is destroyed to free up memory. In your case storing `uploadProperties` should be enough.

In your Activity, first store it when it's being destroyed (I assume your `Property` class is `Parcelable`, if not write whatever you need to be able to restore it later):

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    // ( ... your save instance states if any)
    // store upload properties if they were set up
    if(::uploadProperties.isInitialized)
        outState.putParcelable("uploadProperties", uploadProperties)
}
```

then restore it somewhere in your `onCreate`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // (...)
    if(savedInstanceState?.containsKey("uploadProperties") == true){
        uploadProperties = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("uploadProperties")!!
    }
    // (...)
}
```

Now alter your result callback so it's delayed until after your properties are restored:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        when (requestCode) {
            REQ_FILE -> {
                data?.let {
                    val base64 = data.toBase64()
                    // delay using androidx.lifecycle
                    lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
                        uploadProperties.let { it.value = base64 }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i miss the part to delay the result callback. I don't know that onActivityResult is called before onCreate